# How to find the owner and group name from uid and gid using system calls listed in man 2 pages?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have an assignment in which I have to simulate ls -l unix command using C. I have figured out everything except finding the owner and the group of a particular file. I have the uid and gid from the stat structure using stat() system call, but I am not able to map them to the actual name of the user and owner respectively. I am supposed to use only those system calls which are listed in the man 2 pages. I have tried searching for an answer, but everywhere it says to use getpwnam() call, which I can't as it is not listed in the man 2 pages.

Comment: `getpguid(uid_t uid)` and `getgrgid(gid_t gid)` (they are on the same manpage here as the ones based on name) Both return a ponter to a (static) structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *getpwnam(3)* and *getgrnam(3)* are the ways you'd do this in settings not restricted to system calls only.

But even reading the contents of `/etc/passwd` using only system calls poses a challenge or two. Regular friends like *fopen(3)*, *fread(3)* and *fgets(3)* aren't available, nor are string helpers like *strsep(3)*. I guess you're stuck with *read(2)*. You can read one character at a time using *read(2)*, and do a crude parse of contents that way.

Or you could set up a character array that's big enough to read all of `/etc/passwd` into memory, and walk over the file contents that way. You'll have info *stat(2)* returned to tell how big `/etc/passwd` is, so could either fail if it's too big for your assumptions, or implement a buffering strategy yourself.

Or you could look into *sbrk(2)*, and be sure you've enough memory to land all of `/etc/passwd` in memory from one *read(2)*.

However you read the contents, you'll have some conversion to do of text -- strings of digits -- to C numeric types, harder when *atoi(3)* isn't available.

Also fun: converting `time_t` (*time(2)* output; also some of the fields of `struct stat`) to a nice string:

`1409264099 -> Thu Aug 28 17:14:59 2014`

Are these really the rules of the assignment...? C is crude enough without the presence of a conventional `libc`...

Answer (score 0):

You can search the `/etc/passwd` file for what you require. You can find out the structure of the `/etc/passwd` file with `man 5 passwd`. There is no system call that will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Only system calls... oh dear!

Well, I would mmap `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` and search the memory regions using basic C operations. Both files are line oriented, so lines are separated by `\n`, and within each line the entries are separated by colons.